# How to add HTTP Headers Logback Logstash

Tags: http-headers, logstash, logback, request-headers, logstash-logback-encoder

I read through the following documentation but cannot figure out what other configuration I need: https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#header-fields

My config file:

```
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />

    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />

    <property name="LOG_FILE" value="${LOG_FILE:-${LOG_PATH:-${LOG_TEMP:-${java.io.tmpdir:-/tmp}}}/spring.log}"/>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
            <customFields>{"app_name":"${APP_NAME:-N/A}","app_version":"${APP_VERSION:-N/A}","hostname":"${HOST:-N/A}","environment":"${environment:-${ENVIRONMENT:-N/A}}"}</customFields>
            <includeContext>false</includeContext>
            <timeZone>UTC</timeZone>
       </encoder>

      <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashAccessEncoder">
        <fieldNames>
            <requestHeaders>request_headers</requestHeaders>
        </fieldNames>
      </encoder>

        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE_ROTATION:-${LOG_FILE}%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i}</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>${LOG_FILE_ROTATION_MAX_HISTORY:-1}</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>${LOG_FILE_ROTATION_TOTAL_SIZE_CAP:-3GB}</totalSizeCap>
            <maxFileSize>${LOG_FILE_ROTATION_MAX_FILE_SIZE:-1GB}</maxFileSize>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <root level="${LOG_LEVEL:-INFO}">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@19:29 - no applicable action for [requestHeaders], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][encoder][fieldNames][requestHeaders]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The xml configuration file you provided appears to be for [logback-classic](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/index.html) (since it includes `<root level=...`).

Automatic logging of request headers by logstash-logback-encoder is only available for  `IAccessEvent`s logged via [logback-access](https://logback.qos.ch/access.html).

In other words, automatic logging of request headers is *not* available for `ILoggingEvent`s logged via a `Logger` from logback-classic.  However, you can manually include them when using logback-classic as described below.

### Logging of request headers with logback-access

To log request headers for `IAccessEvent`s logged via logback-access, follow the instructions for setting up logback-access for tomcat or jetty, and add the following to your `logback-access.xml`.  (Note this is *not* the `logback.xml` file used by logback-classic)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashAccessEncoder">
            <fieldNames>
                <requestHeaders>request_headers</requestHeaders>
            </fieldNames>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender-ref ref="console"/>

</configuration>
```

This configuration was tested using logstash-logback-encoder 5.3.  Note that the xml element names are different in logstash-logback-encoder versions prior to 5.0, so ensure you are using 5.0+ with that configuration.

### Logging of request headers with logback-classic

logstash-logback-encoder does not provide first-class support for logging request headers via logback-classic.  However, you include them in a log event logged via a `Logger` by using [event-specific custom fields](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#event-specific-custom-fields).

For example, in a class that has access to the http request (such as a servlet filter), you could do something like this:

```java
Map<String, String> httpHeadersMap = ...; // get http request headers as a map
LOGGER.info("request", StructuredArguments.entries(httpHeadersMap));
```

and configure a `LogbackEncoder` in your `logback.xml` like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder"/>
    </appender>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```